# Java Mail: Setting Chinese Encoding

Tags: java, utf-8, jakarta-mail

I sent myself a Chinese email  via gmail and I received it successfully with the following headers
[image: Successful email header]

When I send a Chinese email via javax.mail it appears as follows in my mail browser
[image: failed email]

The header for the failed email is as follows:
[image]

My code is as follows:

```
    public boolean send() throws TestReportingException, MessagingException
    {
        try
        {

            String encodingOptions = "text/plain; charset=UTF-8";

            Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator()
            {
                // override the getPasswordAuthentication method
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
                {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                }
            };

            // Create the mail session
            Session session = Session.getInstance(maileProperties, authenticator);

            MimeMessage mimeMessage = new MimeMessage(session);
            mimeMessage.setHeader("Content-Type", encodingOptions);

            // Set From: header field of the header.
            mimeMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from, fromName));

            // Set To: header field of the header.
            for (String s : toList)
            {
                if (null == s)
                {
                    throw new TestReportingException("Email address is null");
                }
                mimeMessage.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(s));
            }

            for (String s : ccList)
            {
                mimeMessage.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC, InternetAddress.parse(s));
            }

            // Set Subject: header field
            mimeMessage.setSubject(subject,"UTF-8");

            // Create the message part
            //MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        //    messageBodyPart.setContent(message, encodingOptions);

            // Create the message part
            MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            mimeMessage.setHeader("Content-Type", encodingOptions);
            // Now set the actual message
            messageBodyPart.setText(message, "utf-8", "plain");

            // Now set the actual message
            //messageBodyPart.setText(message, "utf-8", "html");

            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

            // Set text message part
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);



            // Part two is attachment
            if (null != attachmentSource)
            {
                messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

                messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(attachmentSource));
                messageBodyPart.setFileName(attachmentSource.getName());
                multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

            }

            // Send the complete message parts
            mimeMessage.setContent(multipart);


            // Send message
            //Transport.send(mimeMessage);

            SSm.getLogger().debug("Subject: "+mimeMessage.getSubject());




            Transport.send(mimeMessage);

            SSm.getLogger().info("\n\nSent message successfully....");

            clear();

            return true;

        }
        catch (MessagingException mex)
        {
            SSm.getLogger().error(mex.getMessage());
            throw mex;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            SSm.getLogger().error(e.getMessage(), e);
            throw new TestReportingException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
```

Properties are:

- host =smtp.gmail.com
- mail.smtp.auth=true
- mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true mail.smtp.host=smtp.gmail.com
- mail.smtp.port=587 mail.mime.charset=UTF-8

**NOTES**:
The text is not corrupted before it is sent. 
message.getSubject() prints out as clean Chinese text
I am guessing something is wrong with the way I did the encoding

EDIT

Here's the debug output:

> DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.5.5
>
> DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
>
> DEBUG SMTP: need username and password for authentication
>
> DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
>
> DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 587, isSSL false
>
> 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP s20sm18171725pfg.11 - gsmtp
>
> DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "smtp.gmail.com", port: 587

>

> EHLO jake-yoga3.hitronhub.home
>
> 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [96.49.181.179]
>
> 250-SIZE 35882577
>
> 250-8BITMIME
>
> 250-STARTTLS
>
> 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
>
> 250-PIPELINING
>
> 250-CHUNKING
>
> 250 SMTPUTF8
>
> DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "35882577"
>
> DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
>
> DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "STARTTLS", arg ""
>
> DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
>
> DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
>
> DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "CHUNKING", arg ""
>
> DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SMTPUTF8", arg ""
>
> STARTTLS
>
> 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
>
> EHLO jake-yoga3.hitronhub.home
>
> 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [96.49.181.179]
>
> 250-SIZE 35882577
>
> 250-8BITMIME
>
> 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH
>
> 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
>
> 250-PIPELINING
>
> 250-CHUNKING
>
> 250 SMTPUTF8
>
> DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "35882577"
>
> DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
>
> DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH"
>
> DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
>
> DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
>
> DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "CHUNKING", arg ""
>
> DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SMTPUTF8", arg ""
>
> DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate using mechanisms: LOGIN PLAIN DIGEST-MD5 NTLM XOAUTH2
>
> DEBUG SMTP: Using mechanism LOGIN
>
> DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN command trace suppressed
>
> DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN succeeded
>
> DEBUG SMTP: use8bit false
>
> MAIL FROM:
>
> 250 2.1.0 OK s20sm18171725pfg.11 - gsmtp
>
> RCPT TO:
>
> 250 2.1.5 OK s20sm18171725pfg.11 - gsmtp
>
> DEBUG SMTP: Verified Addresses
>
> DEBUG SMTP:   JSTONE@I-KODA.COM
>
> DATA
>
> 354  Go ahead s20sm18171725pfg.11 - gsmtp
>
> From: iKoda Report
>
> To: JSTONE@I-KODA.COM
>
> Message-ID: <1926337998.1.1488002481716@jake-yoga3>
>
> Subject: =?UTF-8?B?QnZ4Y2Igw6TCuMKtIMOkwrjCrSDDpMK4wq0gw6TCuMKtIMOkwrjCrQ==?=
>
> MIME-Version: 1.0
>
> Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
>
> ```
>    boundary="----=_Part_0_1855484302.1488002481637"
> ```

>

> ------=_Part_0_1855484302.1488002481637
>
> Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
>
> Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

>

> RGVhciBaeGN2LA0KDQpCdnhjYiDDpMK4wq0gw6TCuMKtIMOkwrjCrSDDpMK4wq0gw6TCuMKtw6TC
>
> uMKtIMOkwrjCrSDDpMK4wq0gw6TCuMKtIMOkwrjCrWh0dHBzOi8vd3d3Lmkta29kYS5jb20vZGVs
>
> aXZlcnkvZHNmcj91ZnQ9MTAxMjc3MCZjPTEwMTI3NjTDpMK4wq0gw6TCuMKtIMOkwrjCrSDDpMK4
>
> wq0gw6TCuMKt
>
> ------=_Part_0_1855484302.1488002481637--
>
> .
>
> 250 2.0.0 OK 1488002489 s20sm18171725pfg.11 - gsmtp
>
> DEBUG SMTP: message successfully delivered to mail server
>
> QUIT
>
> 221 2.0.0 closing connection s20sm18171725pfg.11 - gsmtp
>
> [INFO] "jake.app" com.ikoda.service.utilities.EmailOut.send(EmailOut.java:256) 01:27:

>

> Sent message successfully....

>

Comment: First, fix these [common JavaMail mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).

Did you copy your code from [this other post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42447635/javax-mail-utf-8-encoding-issue)?  Even the comments are surprisingly similar.

What version of JavaMail are you using?  What does the [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) show?

Comment: yes, I reposted as the other post had a major human error in it. I'm not seeing any of the common errors, The authenticator may not be ideal, but it works.

I'll look into the javamail logs. Thanks for the tip

Comment: What major human error?  And, fix Session.getDefaultInstance.  "It works" is not the same as "it's correct".  None of these are probably the cause of your problem, but that's why I want to see the JavaMail debug output.

Comment: oops, OK. I've fixed that. I have also added the debug output from javax.mail.
I am unusually stick on this. I usually get through this kind of issues in a couple of hours. Any advice would be deeply appreciated

Comment: You're using a slightly old version of JavaMail, but I don't see any obvious problems.  Do you see the same message content when using "view source" in your mail browser?  Exactly what mail browser are you using?  The problem may be that your mail reader isn't interpreting or displaying the message properly.

Comment: I'm using gmail. I've been scratching my head on this all day. It may have something to do with the way I am encoding the Chinese. I'll look into that as well.

Comment: If you send the message from Gmail to Gmail and it works, you should be able to construct an equivalent message using JavaMail.  Your first example above looks like the Subject isn't encoded at all, which is definitely a mistake.  Is your browser running in a Chinese locale?  That may be the only reason that works.  You might want to try reading the messages using another mail reader such as Thunderbird.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Problem was not in the code shown above. The problem was in concatenating ANSI to UTF-8 text when preparing the email message and subject Strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem.
The problem was NOT in the Email class and only tangentially related to javamail.
(so the code above is correct)

The problem is in extracting the text from a hotwired instance of Spring's MessageBundle in my Controller.

I INCORRECTLY used the following code so that my logging class could log the Strings pulled from the message bundle.

```
byte[] barray =messageSource.getMessage(code, null, LocaleContextHolder.getLocale()).getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    String s = new String(barray);
```

Log4j could read the  Strings in the subject and message (built by StringBuilder) which led me to believe that the Strings were in correct UTF-8. However, javax.mail garbled the in transmission.

What I should have done is this:

```
messageSource.getMessage(code, null, LocaleContextHolder.getLocale())
```

Now my logger just gets ???, but the email sends just fine.

So, Keep It Simple Stupid.

Comment: The ??? might just be the console not supporting the Chinese characters, and them getting replaced by a ? instead.

Comment: It isn't, because the ?? appears both on console and log file until I convert using getBytes. Then the characters appear in both.

But, I'm not too concerned about this issue. It would be trivial to have a utility method for converting before logging if I needed it.

Comment: Your console uses a specific encoding that doesn't contain Chinese characters, so when the logging is written, those characters get replaced by a question mark. That is also illustrated by your use of `new String(barray)`, because that reinterprets the bytes in the default character set of your system (which isn't UTF-8, so you are probably on Windows). BTW: Using `new String(barray)` is bad because you don't specify an explicit character set, which might make your application behave differently when run on another platform (say Linux, where the default character set usually is UTF-8)